# Unable to Login to Apple ID through Xcode Preferences

Tags: xcode, apple-id

in Xcode Preferences. I am getting following Error. I have other Apple ID where I can login. I have attached screen shot along with it. Please let me know why I am getting such error.[Following is error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlnWH.png)

Comment: did yo got solutions>?

Comment: @TejasArdeshna Did u get any solutions?

Comment: @MonikaPatel Yeah, It was firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following commands in Terminal:

sudo mkdir -p /Users/Shared
sudo chown root:wheel /Users/Shared
sudo chmod -R 1777 /Users/Shared